# 2 entities 1 form Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, doctrine

A bit familiar with symfony until I found myself in the middle of this.

I have two entities: user and accounts.

**Each user has a series of accounts** like google account, facebook account ,etc. Users are in one table and the accounts in a different table. Obviously, accounts are fetched based on the user's id.

How can I merge both entities into one form so I can fetch, create, edit and/or delete entries?

**my user entity:**

```
use statements here
...
private $id;
private $fullname;
private $accounts;

public function __construct(){
 $this->accounts = new ArrayCollection();
}    
//setters and getters...
```

**my account entity:**

```
use statements here
...
private $id;
private $user_id; //id in user entity
private $service; //i.e google account
private $username;
private $password;

//setters and getters...
```

**My user form:**

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
...
    $builder
        ->add('id',HiddenType::class)
        ->add('FullName',TextType::class)
        ->add('accounts'.,CollectionType::class,[
             'entry_type' => AccountType::class
         ])
 ...
 public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User'
    ));
}
```

**Accounts form:**

```
class AccountType extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
...
    $builder
        ->add('id',HiddenType::class)
        ->add('accountname',TextType::class) //i.e Google Account
        ->add('username',TextType::class)
        ->add('password',TextType::class)
 ...
 public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Account'
    ));
}
```

**My controller:**

```
...      
 @Route("/users/{id}/edit")
...
public function EditAction(Request $request, User $user){
...
$form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
$form->handleRequest($request);
...
...
return $this->render("/pages/users/edit.html.twig",
  ["form"=>$form->createView()]
);
```

No errors at all, but form is not displaying any of the fields for the accounts entity.

```
i,e,. {{ form_row(accounts.username) }}
```

Any ideas or help or pointing me to the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `->add('accounts'.CollectionType::class` there is a dot, and you missed a comma before third parameter.

Comment: Does your User currently have any accounts?  Need at least one to show any account fields.

Comment: Yes there are accounts and/or data in both tables.

Comment: Mateusz Sip that's just a typo here. Already fixed.

Comment: I suppose it could be your twig.  Especially where you loop over the accounts.  Have you tried just doing a {{ form(form) }} to see what you get?  And this is off topic, but are you trying to get people to enter their actual google passwords?  That seems a bit iffy.

Comment: This script will be implemented to work with Google/Facebook Apps. Technically, we will create the google account for the user and give the password to them, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call a form inside another form like this calling its Type:

```
 $builder
    ->add('id',HiddenType::class)
    ->add('FullName',TextType::class)
    ->add('accounts', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new AccountType(), 
            'allow_add' => true,))
```

Comment: This triggers an error. This most likely will work in symfony 2.x

Comment: 'Could not load type "collection"
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException'

Comment: Have you added the use for AccountType?

Comment: To the controller? Yes I did.

Comment: No inside user form class where you call AccountType class

Answer (score 0):

Answer was actually pretty easy. All I needed was to add the proper annotation to the $accounts property.

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Account")
*
private $accounts;
```

Thanks for all of your inputs. Whole script is now working